# Convert some VB bit fidding to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, bit-manipulation

I came across this in some very old VB code:

```
If (Ans.FormatFlags And StringFormatFlags.NoClip) <> 0 Then
    FF = FF And Not StringFormatFlags.NoClip
```

I'm not 100% sure what this is trying to do, but I think it's seeing if the flag "is not set" in FF?

If so, what is the equivalent C#...

```
!StringFormatFlags.NoClip
```

doesn't work because you can't apply ! to a StringFormatFlags.

```
!(int)StringFormatFlags.NoClip
```

doesn't work because you can't apply ! to a int.

Do I use != 0 here or is there a simpler in-line method?

Comment: google works wonders... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformatflags(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm guessing `Ans.FormatFlags` is of type `StringFormatFlags`, so the "if" statement checks if the NoClip flag is set. The second statement unsets it in FF, so to unset a flag with boolean operations you would use the tilde (~), like `FF &= ~StringFormatFlags.NoClip`, as long as FF is also of type `StringFormatFlags`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe these are bitwise operators. The meaning of the statement is "if Ans.FormatFlags has the bit StringFormatFlags.NoClip set, clear StringFormatFlags.NoClip from FF". So your statement can be like this:

```
if ((Ans.FormatFlags & StringFormatFlags.NoClip) != 0)
    FF = FF & (~(int)StringFormatFlags.NoClip);
```

or

```
if (Ans.FormatFlags.HasFlag(StringFormatFlags.NoClip))
    FF &= (~(int)StringFormatFlags.NoClip);
```

(UPDATED: Thanks to theB for Enum's HasFlag and Maury for the mising type cast)

Comment: You could also check the flag with the slightly more idiomatic: `Ans.FormatFlags.HasFlag(StringFormatFlags.NoClip)`

Comment: why the extra parenthesis?

Comment: I think I like the HasFlag solution because it clearly states what it's trying to do. Thanks guys, works like a champ!

Comment: Actually it required one minor change: ` FF &= (~(int)StringFormatFlags.NoClip); `

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell the statement says, "if the NoClip flag is set, then clear the related flag in FF." In C# try:

```
if ((Ans.FormatFlags & StringFormatFlags.NoClip) != 0)
   FF = FF & !StringFormatFlags.NoClip;
```

Comment: That doesn't compile... did you mean to use the bitwise not operator (`~`)?